# Is there a way to run cucumber tests with real production data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, cucumber, bdd

I've been trying cucumber to create new features for our project, but it's been very hard to find a way to run the tests against real data. I have to create entities of everything with Factory Girl in order to run them properly, am I doing it wrong? Or cucumber it's only to do every flow step by step, creating fake data? Will I be better off trying the Steak approach? (Rspec-Capybara)?

Please let me know if someone has faced this issue when having a project already running with a bunch of features and you are adding the TDD-BDD to your duties.

Comment: You can simply copy production database to your testing environment and use real models instead of mocks.

Comment: But everytime I run a cucumber tests it removes all data from it, because of the seeds.rb file, and then at the end of the test it truncates everything, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @tr9sh this one [link](https://github.com/cavalle/steak)

Comment: I'd like to be able to run my cucumber tests against my production database data in a staging environment so I can confirm that the commit won't break anything in production.

Answer (score 1):

The point of FactoryGirl and other fixture libraries is to produce data without relying on production imports. Importing data from production to run your tests suggests that the behaviour you are testing for is not actually the behaviour that is occurring in production.

New or old functionality, if your behaviour is known then define it with cucumber. Start small, select a piece of functionality that is simple and create your `.feature` file. Define you step_definitions on what you know to be the correct behaviour. Then if your tests fail then fix it in your application code rather than cucumber.

Ensure that your step definitions are doing black box tests. They don't need to know the internal state of the function they are testing, they only want to work with the known inputs and test the result.

Comment: Alright I understand the factory girl prupose, but if I'm adding new functionality to an existing app that don't have previous cucumber testing, then I need to have real data to validate a feature that is completely new, because of the dependencies and relationships between entities, so my question now for you is that cucumber is only to define scenarios that you think it might work in a project that has started and you are building each feature from the beginning with no data, but your assumptions, am I correct?